# FB.login pop up is blocked when page on load

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, popup

I'm facing an issue when calling FB.login when page on load, the FB.login pop up is block by the browser. Currently I know I've to call FB.login after a user click event but I've to do it this way due to the business logic from client.

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response2) {
    var permsArray = response2.data[0];
    var permsNeeded = ["user_events"]; 

    var permsToPrompt = [];
    for (var i in permsNeeded) {
       if (permsArray[permsNeeded[i]] == null) { 
        permsToPrompt.push(permsNeeded[i]);
      }
    }   

    if (permsToPrompt.length > 0) {
      promptForPerms(permsToPrompt);
    }
});



var promptForPerms = function(perms) {
    FB.login(function(response) {
    }, {scope: perms.join(',')});
};
```

Is there any solution to call FB.login() without user click event? Or is there any tweak for this? Appreciate for the help.

Comment: No, you can not work around my popup blocker – because that would mean it would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to code your way around the popup blocker, unfortunately.

The way to solve this is by redirecting the user to the Facebook permissions dialog when the page loads as described in the docs for [manually building a login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow).

You first need to detect if the user is authenticated / connected with your application already and only redirect if they are not connected. This is best done in the `window.fbAsyncInit` function like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    var myAppID = 'YOUR APPLICATION ID';

    FB.init({ appId: myAppID });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if ('connected' != response.status) {
            window.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth' +
                '?client_id=' + myAppID +
                '&scope=user_events' +
                '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
        } else {
            alert('welcome to my app');
        }
    });

};
```

The other option is to adjust your user journey slightly; perhaps if the user is not connected then you could display an overlay with a message asking them to authenticate and a button which when clicked calls FB.login.